# Python: re.sub replaces only 16 times

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following string

```
s = '\t 1\n\t 2\n\t 3\n\t 4\n\t 5\n\t 6\n\t 7\n\t 8\n\t 9\n\t 10\n\t 11\n\t 12\n\t 13\n\t 14\n\t 15\n\t 16\n\t 17\n\t 18\n\t'
```

I want to start each (indented) row with the string 'item'. So I write

```
s = re.sub('\t', '\t\item ', s, re.DOTALL)
```

The output I get is:

```
    \item  1
    \item  2
    \item  3
    \item  4
    \item  5
    \item  6
    \item  7
    \item  8
    \item  9
    \item  10
    \item  11
    \item  12
    \item  13
    \item  14
    \item  15
    \item  16
     17
     18
```

Why is the operation only performed the first 16 times?

Comment: Because the value of `re.DOTALL` is 16. You're passing it not as a flag, but as a `count` argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = re.sub('\t', '\t\item ', s, re.DOTALL)
```

is the equivalent of

```
s = re.sub('\t', '\t\item ', s, count=re.DOTALL)
```

with `re.DOTALL` being 16, as the signature of `sub` is

```
sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

You want this:

```
s = re.sub('\t', '\t\item ', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I see, great, thanks!